# Error getimagesize(): SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php, ssl, xampp

I made XAMPP run locally with SSL and it was possible to access the site with HTTPS. However, when you try to use image-related functions, such as PHP's getimagesize(), it gives the error below:

```
Warning: getimagesize(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in C:\xampp\htdocs\gebrascam\controllers\ajaxController.php on line 560

Warning: getimagesize(): Failed to enable crypto in C:\xampp\htdocs\gebrascam\controllers\ajaxController.php on line 560
```

I generated a local certificate and pointed to it on the server when I created the SSL.
Searching about the error, I thought I should change the path where openssl.cafile was pointed, but I made the change and it didn't solve.

Would you have any idea how to solve it or even find a way forward?

Comment: No, I had already seen this post, I tested it and it didn't work! @KIKOSoftware

Comment: This is unrelated to getimagesize. It simply has problems accessing the given remote resource because certificate validation failed. Why it failed is unknown - it could be a server problem of not setting up the certificate properly, could be improperly setup trust store on your site ...

Comment: Steffen Ullrich would it be this?